# How to stop clang AST misinterpreting this type of function declaration as a variable declaration?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using clang's abstract syntax tree generation to generate an AST for some source files. It maps out normal functions great, however it trips up on some functions, mislabeling them as variable declarations. When it does this it waits for a semicolon to finish this declaration and so does not map out the rest of the source file following the problem function. Is there a way to make clang realize that it's a function definition, not a variable declaration?

I put a semicolon after the function definition and doing that makes clang ignore the contents of the function, but at least it generates nodes for the code following it in the source file. I'm using the prophy python interface to interact with clang in my scripts, but ran clang manually and found the same thing.

This is an example of a function that clang does map:

```c
int killProcess(int pid)
{
    int ret=1;

    HANDLE pHandle;

    if ((pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,pid)) != NULL)
        if(!TerminateProcess(pHandle,0)) {
            ret=0;
            CloseHandle(pHandle);
        }

    return ret;
}
```

This is an example of a function which clang thinks is a variable declaration and ignores everything after it if there is no semicolon after the closing brace:

```c
DWORD WINAPI listProcessesThread(LPVOID param)
{
    char sendbuf[IRCLINE];

    LPROC lproc = *((LPROC *)param);
    LPROC *lprocp = (LPROC *)param;
    lprocp->gotinfo = TRUE;

    sprintf(sendbuf,"[PROC]: Listing processes:");
    if (!lproc.silent) irc_privmsg(lproc.sock,lproc.chan,sendbuf,lproc.notice);

    if (listProcesses(lproc.sock,lproc.chan,lproc.notice,NULL, FALSE, lproc.full) == 0)
        sprintf(sendbuf,"[PROC]: Process list completed.");
    else
        sprintf(sendbuf,"[PROC]: Process list failed.");

    if (!lproc.silent) irc_privmsg(lproc.sock, lproc.chan, sendbuf, lproc.notice);
    addlog(sendbuf);

    clearthread(lproc.threadnum);

    ExitThread(0);
}
```

The expected results would be that clang knows that this is a function and generates a corresponding AST, however it doesn't. It constructs a VAR_DECL node with the spelling "WINAPI" instead of a "FUNCTION_DECL" node. The error it gives upon running "clang -cc1 -ast-dump processes2.cpp" is:

`-VarDecl 0x5625ad7ab2e0  col:7 invalid WINAPI 'int'
1 error generated.

At the end of its log. The abstract syntax tree up until this point is generated and displayed.

NB: I do not have WINAPI library installed because I am working on a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: You cannot expect Clang to magically know `WINAPI` is a macro with some `__declspec` or `__attribute__` behind it. If you generate an AST, you must be able to compile the code in question.

Comment: If you get same behavior with or without using Python, why is this tagged with Python?

Comment: If you don't have `windows.h` around/included, `clang` has no idea how to interpret `WINAPI`. You may not need to be on Windows, but you definitely need the headers to parse it properly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger would you recommend then installing clang on a Windows machine and doing this, or is there a way to get all of these libraries on Linux in a way that the compiler will recognise?